# how to Importing modules python

Tags: python, python-3.x, imdbpy

I'm learning about how to import libraries from directories and I've stumbled upon an error I can't seem to figure out. I'm using the IMDBpy python library in a folder called lib. Below, I am importing the module which no longer returns any errors, but when I move to line number 6, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testlib.py", line 4, in <module>
    from lib.imdb import IMDb
  File "/home/user/Scripts/test/lib/imdb/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    import imdb._logging
ImportError: No module named 'imdb'
```

Python is throwing an error because the python test file I'm writing is 2 directories up. Not sure how to get it working without putting everything in the same directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from lib.imdb import IMDb

# Create the object that will be used to access the IMDb's database.
ia = imdb.IMDb() # by default access the web.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either write:

```
from lib.imdb import IMDb

ia = IMDb()
```

or:

```
from lib import imdb

ia = imdb.IMDb()
```

But importing `IMDb` and then calling `imdb.IMDb()` does not work.

One other point to mention: If your *testlib.py* resides above the `lib` foder, then you need to add a `__init__.py` file within `lib` for your import to work. The file can be completely empty.

---

**Update**: This packages uses import statement that are not relative to the package folder, but to an arbitrary folder in `sys.path`. An illustration of this is the exact line that causes the error:

```
# imdb.__init__.py
imdb._logging
```

This works only if the packages resides in a folder that is part of `sys.path`, so either in the same path as the script that does the `from imdb import IMDb` statement or in the python dist-package path (simplified explanation). This and all equivalent imports could be replaced by

```
# imdb.__init__.py
from . import _logging
```

In which case the import is relative to the module, so there is no need for the imdbpy package to reside in a directory in `sys.path`.

The consequence for us now is that we cannot simply put imdb in a sub-folder, we need to either put it in a folder from `sys.path` or add the folder it resides in to `sys.path`. So, the options are:

- install the package
- move the imdb folder up into the current folder
- write:

  ```
  import sys
  sys.path.insert(0, 'absolute/path/to/lib')
  ```

  before the import statement.

In any of the above cases you will be able to do:

```
from imdb import IMDb
ia = IMDb()
```

Comment: I've tried both the examples you provided and it did not work. I get the exact error as above.

Comment: I had already done that which is why I was finally able to import, this is the second hurdle i'm facing. When I ran the script after putting that, I got a new directory called __pycache__ and a file named __init__.pyc automatically.

Comment: @yusof I've been looking at the [imdbpy](https://github.com/alberanid/imdbpy) package a bit more closely. Funny enough, if you replace all imports of type `import imdb.xxx` with relative import like `from . import xxx` then everything runs smoothly. What should work is adding it to sys.path, so `import sys, os` then `sys.path.insert(0, 'absolute/path/to/lib')`.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned above, it is different importing an object from importing a function.
When you import a module such as `imdb` you may use its functions. However, when you import a function, you can only use that function, not the object/module where it came from.

Check this for better examples: [Python 3 modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#modules)